# How do 'npc' servers delete my software?

Tags: hacker-experience

In hacker experience there are quite a few 'npc' (maybe Non Playable Servers (NPS)?) servers. These servers dont retaliate for anything you do to them so they are a popular target to plant your spamware, virus or miner. Now i was wondering, is there a set time when your software gets deleted from their server? Is this time level bound? For example if i upload a version 10 will it stay on there longer then a version 2? Is there a way to make sure my warez stay on their server longer/forever?

Comment: I haven't played in a while, but I'm pretty sure each NPS (I like your terminology) has something like a Software Reset Timer? It should be visible when logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NPC servers have both Software and Hardware reset timers.  You can think of the Software reset as a "re-image" in real life, they reset the software to their usual set up, completely formatting the drive and restoring what they had originally, the only way to be entirely sure they got everything.  The Hardware reset is a replacement time in case someone DDOS's their hardware into oblivion.

The reason for the resets is because the NPC servers are important for the Missions, and if too much stuff has been uploaded / the file you need has been deleted / the server can't hold the file you need to upload because their hard drive was DDOS'd back to vacuum tubes, you need only wait for the next reset for the server to be fixed and you can complete your mission.

This makes them only short-term benefits for your various miners.  Inactive or barely active players are a better option, although you'll get the most money (and the most risk) by stealing from more active players.

Comment: From what I've seen lately, software reset seems to recover their pre-existing original softwares, without formatting the drive (it keeps all the viruses installed on it). The drive format is executed when the hardware reset occurs. Which means the software you want to get on a NPC server might not be there for 3-4 hours if the hard drive is full, until the next hardware reset, and the viruses *survive* the length of an hardware reset timer (until the next HW reset).